# Illegal exception : HSSF-style external references are not supported for XSSF

Tags: java, excel

I tried to evaluate the formula in .xlsx spread sheet. I got the "illegal Exception" error. Anyone guide me to about this issue.

```
Cell cellDB_AcctNumber = row1.createCell(lastCell1);
                cellDB_AcctNumber.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cellDB_AcctNumber.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP($E"+k+",'C:/Vivekanandan/Compare/["+tempPath.getName()+"]\"VKT_AGENCY_BANK_INFO_TEMP\"'!$B$2:$E$"+lastrowDB+",2,FALSE)");
            Cell value = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cellDB_AcctNumber);
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HSSF-style external references are not supported for XSSF
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheet(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:267)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:76)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.getArea3DEval(OperationEvaluationContext.java:259)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:611)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:493)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:287)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:229)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:268)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:183)
    at com.sentry.comparison.compareexcel.CompareSpreadSheets.compareExcelResult(CompareSpreadSheets.java:93)
    at com.sentry.comparison.main.FinalComparisonResult.main(FinalComparisonResult.java:45)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the cell type for CELL_TYPE_FORMULA?

Comment: Thanks Scrappedcola,  Even i tried setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA); its showing the same error. i googled but i didnt get proper scenarios.